# What component is this? Need identify

Tags: diodes, identification, zener

What component is this? It's from a led light strip on a backlight on a car.

[image: Diode]

Comment: The logo is that of General Semiconductor, acquired by Vishay in 2001. However the part numbers/date codes don't match anything that I could find. ([Vishay's markings guide](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88912/diodesgroupbodymarking.pdf).)

Comment: What are the package dimensions, what device/product is it in, and what function does it perform in the circuit?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmdDN.jpg . This is the full board. Sorry but this is my first post here and I am not used to this.  I also guess that it's a zener.

Comment: If it's a TVS surge-suppress diode, then it might be 33V bi-directinoal zener, SMBJ33A, with "CM" marking code, 1992 date code.  The bi-directional versions need no diode-stripe.  It should measure as open circuit, unless you applied big spikes above 33V

Answer (score 0):

It's an E-96 series SMD resistor with a tolerance of ± 1 %.

The number 92A is the Resistor SMD Code in the the EIA-96 System.

http://www.resistorguide.com/resistor-smd-code/

Value code '92' pertains to value 887 and multiplier code 'A' to multiplier 1.

Hence the resistor value is 887Ω ± 1%.